# What does the method em.find do in Entity Manager?

Tags: java

For example, I have database which consist table "menu":

```
Menu c = em.find(Menu.class,name);
```

I do not understand what second field "name" does here.

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest taking a look at [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html). Second parameter is an `@Id` of the entity, whose class is given as the first parameter.

In other words:

```
Menu c = em.find(Menu.class,name);
```

returns an entity of type `Menu` with id `name`.